# Magento 2 Custom options of some products are not visible

Tags: magento2, magento2.1.13

When I add a new product, I tried to import the customizable options from the previous one.

I have saved it after imported the data.

After adding all product, I try to test it on the front-end. Most of the product should work fine like this(pic 1):

[image: showing detail on the cart]

However, without knowing the reason, an issue came out is that some of the product acting weird and missing the custom options like this, only with the attribute color:

[image: only with a color attribute]

Some of the product even look like this, without options to be chosen before adding to cart:

[image: no detail at all]

I checked the admin panel, those products have the data of the customizable options but do not know what is the problem that not showing it. How I solve this is I clicked the save button again, the problem gone and display normally like(pic 1).

I make a guess after some research, is that this kind of issue will happen on 2.1.x version?

I want to know the reason and how to solve it because the issue is happening again and again so I need to check the products on front-end every day now to ensure the products work fine. I have this issue like every day, the issue might not happen on the same product each day.